# Rails dynamically updated View based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to create a view page where the user enters the names of Item objects in a text field, or jquery token field (http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

Each Item has a cost attribute, and I would like to display the total cost dynamicaly, without refreshing, whenever the user adds an item.

So at the top of the page there would be:

"Total Cost: $150", or "Total Cost: $120" if you remove an item that costs $30.

I feel it would be something involving javascript and AJAX but I'm not very proficient with it. Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is a complex question but i will try to help you as far as I can, I would sugest first of all adding that text field to a form, something like this:

show.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "cart_items", :action => :create}, {:method => :post, :remote => true}) do %>                    
    <%= text_field_tag :product_name, product.name %>                          
<%end%>
```

notice the :remote=> true to force rails to do an ajax call

after that in your controller you will need to handle that request so would be something like this:

```
def create     
    if @current_cart==nil
      @current_cart = Cart.create!
      @current_cart.save
      session[:cart] = @current_cart.id
    end
    @product = Product.find_by_name(params[:product_name])
    @current_cart.add(@product, @product.price)      
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {redirect_to :back, :notice => "added"}
      format.html {redirect_to :back, :notice => "added"}
    end    
  end
```

after that you will need some javascript to handle that ajaxt response like this:

show.js.erb:

```
$('.cart').replaceWith('<%= j render :partial => "layouts/cart"%>');
```

the you need a cart parcial to replace:

layouts/_cart.html.erb:

```
<%@current_cart.each do |c| %>
 <%=c.product.name%>
<%end%>
```

im just scratching the surface on a quick answer but maybe you will find some direction
cheers

Answer (score 0):

Would be interested in seeing the relevant view code, but in general you can just add things together to get the total.

If you need to get the value of a text field you can use `.val()` and to convert it to an int or a float you can use `parseInt(string)` or `parseFloat(string)`